# Check a variable in a list with sql

Tags: sql

I have a question concern check a variable if is in a list with SQL

Here my request :

```
select * from states where status in ["Cancelled"", "Won"] limit 10000
```

But I get this error : `42601: syntax error at or near "["`

any idea please?

thnanks

Comment: Use `('Cancelled', 'Won')`.  There are no square braces to represent lists in SQL.

Comment: thanks, I try you propoistion but I get a new error : "cancelled" does not exist in states..

Comment: Square brackets are usually column names. Use single quotes as @GordonLinoff has given you the example, not double quotes. Double quotes is for column names as well.

Comment: You haven't specified your SQL server type, but it is always good if you check the referenece manual for it

Comment: "syntax error" means you typed it in wrong. You should then check online for the correct syntax. E.g. Google "sql in syntax". That will tell you the answer directly without bothering anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes and "()" not "[]".

```
select * 
from states 
where status in ('Cancelled', 'Won')
limit 1000
```